# Disable app library screen

Tags: ios, ipad, applications, children

I have apps on my iPad I don't want my kids seeing (games that I don't want them opening and ruining my progress).

I have done several things for these apps:

- Hide from search
- Disable notifications
- Bury deep in folders

But then Apple released iOS 15 and *boom* suddenly all they need to do is swipe right and there they are! The apps I totally do not want front-and-center are now exactly that.

Is it possible to disable App Library? I suspect no.
Is it possible to remove apps from the App Library? I suspect no.
Is it possible to passcode lock some apps? I suspect no.

Currently whenever I hand them the iPad I specifically put it on an app and turn on guided access. But it would be nice to give them a little more liberty without giving them basically everything.

Any ideas?

Comment: I think the essential issue is that iDevices were never designed to be multi-user. They expect one user on one AppleID per device. Family Sharing gives one or more adults better control of what their children can do, but it still expects one device per user.